# How can I add group in user profile in Active Directory with python?

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

I'm adding user in Active Directory with Python module ldap3. This code is working for me:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SIMPLE, SYNC, ASYNC, SUBTREE, ALL

AD_SERVER = 'w1.sub.company.ltd'
AD_USER = 'admin@sub.company.ltd'
AD_PASSWORD = '123456'
AD_SEARCH_TREE = 'dc=sub,dc=company,dc=ltd'

server = Server(AD_SERVER)
conn = Connection(server, user=AD_USER, password=AD_PASSWORD)
print(conn.bind())

conn.add('CN=John Smith,OU=Users,OU=Admins,DC=sub,DC=company,DC=ltd', 
        ['top', 'person', 'organizationalPerson', 'user'], 
        {'displayName': 'John Smith VIP', 'sn': 'VIP', 'givenName': 'John Smith',
         'sAMAccountName': 'SmithJ', 'userPrincipalName': 'SmithJ', 'userPassword': '123456'})

print(conn.result)
conn.unbind()
```

But if I add attribute "memberOf" in code:

```
conn.add('CN=John Smith,OU=Users,OU=Admins,DC=sub,DC=company,DC=ltd', 
        ['top', 'person', 'organizationalPerson', 'user'], 
        {'memberOf': ['CN=SubAdmins,OU=Groups,OU=Admins,DC=sub,DC=company,DC=ltd'], 
         'displayName': 'John Smith VIP', 'sn': 'VIP', 'givenName': 'John Smith',
         'sAMAccountName': 'SmithJ', 'userPrincipalName': 'SmithJ', 'userPassword': '123456'})
```

Python throws the following error message:

> {'result': 53, 'description': 'unwillingToPerform', 'dn': '', 'message': '0000209A: SvcErr: DSID-031A0FF7, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0\n\x00', 'referrals': None, 'type': 'addResponse'}

I guess my error is in the syntax, but I don't know how to solve it.

1. How can I add group in user profile? (**Solved**)
2. I don't know how add 'userAccountControl': '66048' attribute

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

1. For add user in group:

```
user_dn = 'CN=John Smith,OU=Users,OU=Admins,DC=sub,DC=company,DC=ltd'
get_groups = [('CN=SubAdmins,OU=Groups,OU=Admins,DC=sub,DC=company,DC=ltd')]
conn.extend.microsoft.add_members_to_groups([user_dn], get_groups)
```

2. For add userAccountControle:

```
user_dn = f'CN=John Smith,OU=Users,OU=Admins,DC=sub,DC=company,DC=ltd'
conn.modify(user_dn, {"userAccountControl": (MODIFY_REPLACE, 66050)})
```

Comment: You can't add the memberOf attribute as it is an operationnal attribute (kind of internally maintained) of the directory, so it is only updated if you add/remove a user from a group.

Comment: userAccountControl is an integer ADSI datatype. I don't know python, but you could give a try without the quotes around the '66048' value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solved it:

1.

```
user_dn = 'CN=John Smith,OU=Users,OU=Admins,DC=sub,DC=company,DC=ltd'
get_groups = [('CN=SubAdmins,OU=Groups,OU=Admins,DC=sub,DC=company,DC=ltd')]
conn.extend.microsoft.add_members_to_groups([user_dn], get_groups)
```

2. 

```
user_dn = f'CN=John Smith,OU=Users,OU=Admins,DC=sub,DC=company,DC=ltd'
conn.modify(user_dn, {"userAccountControl": (MODIFY_REPLACE, 66050)})
```